# How to change the default java swing scrollbar with windows style?

Tags: java, swing, microsoft-metro

**So how do you changed the default java swing scrollbar with windows style ?**
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZWCp.png)

*(Metro style I think ?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
  UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

in your main() ?

If that is not the Look and feel you want, maybe give this a read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

Comment: Yes ;) I've tried with `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("Windows");`
and it's work thanks